# Remove facebook user from within the application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Prior to the may updates (we were using the offline tokens because they did not expire), I was able to send a delete request to facebook and remove the user's facebook link from within our software, after turning the disable offline access to enabled (disabled the old functionality), this no longer works. I am trying to figure out what may have changed.  There are no current posts on the subject and all the posts I do find are VERY conflicting in answers.

i.e.

[Remove the application from a user using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634212/remove-the-application-from-a-user-using-graph-api)

vs

[Facebook account delink or deauthorize facebook app and check status of linking from facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679643/facebook-account-delink-or-deauthorize-facebook-app-and-check-status-of-linking)

This is also documented on the graph documentation as saying this command should work, I have tried a few different syntaxes (its not actually stated which syntax to use in the documentation - nice job Facebook, it just says "send a delete request").

Long story short, does this work? I keep getting the 400 error "bad request" when attempting to fix this feature.

I have tried the following two urls:

https://graph.facebook.com/userId/permissions?access_token=someToken&method=delete
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=someToken&method=delete

Answer (score 7):

Those questions aren't inconsistent, one of them was answered before the Graph API had support for this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions is the documentation, the example is:
(javascript)

```
FB.api("/me/permissions","DELETE",function callback());
```

I've done this many times and it definitely works

Comment: I had a feeling that despite their dates being relatively close, that the function was added sometime in between, but I was unable to find the addition documented anywhere, so to me they were indeed inconsistent.

Anyway, we perform all these functions in the server-side code. So a javascript solution would not help. I did find out what my specific problem was and will update though. + For verification that it at least works in JS. 
I'll try to remember to + you when I hit 15 rep and can do that, lol.

Comment: You can definitely make the call with the PHP SDK; the app access token or a currently-valid access token for that user will do it

Comment: The integration code is all in C#.  All these problems had arisen due to using legacy code that never implemented an open source SDK for it. Also I noticed that the facebook C# SDK is deprecated anyway :/.

Thanks though, I only went back to re-check because you said it should work.

Comment: Alright well what about this issue - It worked fine when I had posted back and now it doesn't work at all, again. We get these kinds of issues with facebook's integration ALL the time. Right now any time I try to unlink anything it just gives the 400 Bad Request error with no real information included....Even an SDK is useless if the requests are denied.

Comment: I don't know why, but the callback is never triggered. I'm using the same code as yours. Do you know why the callback is not triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for having answered my own question:

Apparently I was actually getting random errors rather than actual errors.

I am unsure if /me/ works, because I did not go back to re-test it, but I am certain now that using the format:

https://graph.facebook.com/userId/permissions&access_token=someToken

Does indeed work correctly for deauthorizing your own application in facebook.